# Rails load error (no such file to load) after many requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2, passenger

I'm using Apache2 and Rails to host a pretty simple API that uses this: https://github.com/geocommons/geocoder

The other "load error (no such file to load)" problems I've seen online seem to happen at all times and typically in relation to gem files, but my API will get through 1000+ requests before it has this problem.  The file it is unable to load is a controller in my appname/app/controller directory.

After restarting apache the API will work for roughly 1000 more requests.

Error from log file:

> Started GET "/api_uri?[parameters]"
>   for 127.0.0.1 at [timestamp]
>
> LoadError (no such file to load --
>   [dir]/app/controllers/controller_name.rb

The stack trace says something very similar, I can post it if necessary.

I've made sure all of my ruby files require "rubygems", I've made sure my path includes GEM_PATH, GEM_HOME and RUBYOPT in both my environment and my .bashrc file.

Really baffling to me since it appears to work fine at first.  Any ideas?

Update: A memory leak!  The Ruby process slowly climbs to ~10.5% memory usage as the requests continues, and then requests cut out.  Hm

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that the Geocoder gem was not closing transactions or database connections.  Fixed the code and things are now working as expected.